# jquery datepicker validation returns allocation size overload error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i am making a Birth Date input with a jquery datepicker plugin. the plugin works but i wanted to validate that only people with 18 years old birthdate will be allowed. i have tried restricting the year but i am having an error allocation size overload and its referring to the year.

here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    var dateNow = ($.now() - 18);
    $( "#birthdate" ).datepicker({
      yearRange: "1920:" + dateNow,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to check this after user enters the date, use the following snippet.

**[Demo Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/j6R9D/1/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('#birthdate').datepicker({

        changeMonth: true, maxDate: '0',changeYear: true, yearRange: '1900:2014',        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function(){

        var today = new Date(), 
        birthday = $('#birthdate').datepicker("getDate"),
        age = (
          (today.getMonth() > birthday.getMonth())
          ||
          (today.getMonth() == birthday.getMonth() && today.getDate() >= birthday.getDate())
          ) ? today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear() : today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear()-1;

           if(age>=18){
              alert('18+');
           }else{
              alert('not 18');
           }    
       }

   });
});
```

---

If you wish to restrict the users below 18, change `yearRange` attribute of `.datepicker()`

**[Demo For this](http://jsfiddle.net/j6R9D/2/)**.

Comment: this code is well and good but i wanted to restrict the user's option of the drop downs of the date so that they wont be able to pick less than the age permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() - 18);

  $( "#birthdate" ).datepicker({
    yearRange: "1920:" + now.getFullYear(),
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});
```

Comment: That was just an idea to work with. Try the variation to fit the whole.

Comment: try this. it should sort you out.